# Is it a Good practice to have a listView with scroll inside scroll?

Tags: android, listview, scrollview, user-experience

Is it a Good practice to have a list view with scrolling with another scroll for some items inside the listview ? (scroll inside a scroll) .

What do you think about that according UX. I didn't test it on a real device. 
Does there any application follow the same thing ?

### edit

I don't ask how. I already hate it ! But I ask whether it is advisable to have v-scroll inside another v-scroll ?

Comment: First test the same case in your own, you will sure feel it that it is actually a bad idea.

Comment: yes it is easy to use for users.

Comment: Does not it confuse the use , scrolling the inner small scroll or the outer scroll (when touching the screen).?

Comment: if you place a space around your listView it is OK. implement it. you will find it suitable for user. in normal coding it is impossible to have listView inside a ScrollView, but the only way for implementing it, is using my code that has a trick.

my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804774/editis-it-a-good-practice-to-have-a-listview-with-scroll-inside-scroll/7805132#7805132

Answer (score 0):

In case the scrolling of the inside elements is vertical as the listview you can't have it.

But you can have a HorizontalScrollView as child of your listview. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

I think putting a `listview` inside a `scrollview` is discouraged most of the time because both component are able to handle scrolling.

Allowing horizontal scrolling in a `listview` gives a weird user experience so i'm not sure it is advisable anyway.

Comment: you can do it by a trick. test my sample code.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804774/editis-it-a-good-practice-to-have-a-listview-with-scroll-inside-scroll/7805132#7805132

Answer (score 0):

You can have scrollable listView inside of a vertical scroll. use the following code and enjoy!

```
private int listViewTouchAction;
private void setListViewScrollable(final ListView list) {
        list.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                listViewTouchAction = event.getAction();
                if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                    list.scrollBy(0, 1);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                    int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (listViewTouchAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                    list.scrollBy(0, -1);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

listViewTouchAction is a global integer value.